# Progress bar displayed ONLY in web inspector?

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript and D3 to perform some data visualization.  I have a text file containing data I would like to visualize.  I have written the JS code which allows me to upload the file and generate the visualization.

Here is a stripped down version of my JS code:

```
function readInputFile(evt) {
    var f = evt.target.files[0];

    if (f) {
        var r = new FileReader()

         r.onload = function(e) {

        // Generate the visualization

        }

        r.readAsText(f);

    } else {
        alert("Failed to load file");
    }
}

document.getElementById('InputFile').addEventListener('change', readInputFile, false);
```

So far, so standard.

Now, to make the experience more user-friendly, I want to add a loader like http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp which will be displayed while the visualization is being generated.

I notice that if I create the loader within the onload function, the loader is never displayed:

```
function readInputFile(evt) {
    var f = evt.target.files[0];

    if (f) {
        var r = new FileReader()

         r.onload = function(e) {

         d3.select("body")
         .append("div")
         .attr("id", "loader")
         .attr("class", loader)

        // Generate the visualization

        d3.select("#loader").remove()

        }

        r.readAsText(f);

    } else {
        alert("Failed to load file");
    }
}

document.getElementById('InputFile').addEventListener('change', readInputFile, false);
```

However, if I create the loader outside of the onload function, I see the loader:

```
function readInputFile(evt) {
   var f = evt.target.files[0];

   d3.select("body")
         .append("div")
         .attr("id", "loader")
         .attr("class", loader)

    if (f) {
        var r = new FileReader()

         r.onload = function(e) {

        // Generate the visualization

        d3.select("#loader").remove()

        }

        r.readAsText(f);

    } else {
        alert("Failed to load file");
    }
}

document.getElementById('InputFile').addEventListener('change', readInputFile, false);
```

But things really get weird for me when I open web inspector.  To figure out what's going on, I set some breakpoints in the JS code which creates the loader inside the onload function.  But when I run that code with the web inspector open, I see the loader!  I don't get why I would see the loader when I'm in the web inspector but not when I'm running the code without it...

I am using Google Chrome to run my JS code.  I googled about creating progress bars for file uploads and I see a lot of material about using JS with AJAX.  I think AJAX might be overkill for what I want to do but I'm new to JS so I can't be certain.  Plus, that doesn't explain why what I see happening in the web inspector is different from when I just run the code without it.

Thanks for your help!

Augustine

Comment: "*Failed to load file*" should better be "no file selected".

Comment: Your `// Generate the visualization` is synchronous. Which means that it doesn't render anything from the DOM to the screen until all computations finished. A debugger might break this.

Comment: Do you want to show the loader while the file is loading, or after the file has loaded and d3 is initialising?

Comment: @Bergi 

Basically, after reading in the file via readAsText, I do some processing of the file within the onload function before generating the visualization.  So that's why I would have liked to create a progress bar while the onload function is running so that I can show users how the pre-processing is progressing.  

I mentioned before I wanted to use a load spinner but I've decided that I want to use a progress bar like http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp so that users know roughly how fast the file processing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

`onload` is an event triggered when the file is fully loaded. It might be that the loader get removed immediately after it gets rendered. Not sure why web inspector open would affect this, unless that's when those breakpoints you mentioned kick in. I think for what you want to do, you would need to use `onloadstart` and `onloadend` methods. perhaps `onprogress` as well, to update the status of the progress bar. Not sure what support is like for those methods however. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: I thought that onloadstart and onloadend are only supported by audio and video files?

Comment: @auggywonger, it seems like those methods are supported on files as well. You can quickly check in the console by inspecting a new FileReader instance. Not sure about cross-browser support however (I just tested in latest chrome)